# Source texture bad dimensions - WebGL video in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, video, three.js, webgl

Not sure if this is a new problem with Chrome, but video that has been working for ages is suddenly showing as black and I get the below error when rendering.

The video size is 1920x1080

> [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-08FD8CF0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_VALUE :
>   glCopySubTextureCHROMIUM: source texture bad dimensions.

I'm using video as a ShaderMaterial on a sphere for VR video.

Is this something to do with a recent update or something I'm doing!?

Comment: I'm seeing it, too (_Version 57.0.2987.133 unknown (64-bit)
_). I'm using A-Frame to render a video sphere, and A-Frame uses Three.js under the hood. It's funny, but the same video in Chromium (_Version 56.0.2924.76 Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit)_) works.

Comment: Bug in Chrome? https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=701060

Comment: @gman - good find, that looks like it might be the culprit. Maybe the video requires a resolution of "square pixels", which I might have to play around with on my end on the source. Still, it _did_ work before, so I would second the "bug" label they gave it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@gman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128511/gman) for tracking down the bug.

It looks like this is a (known) [regression](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=701060) in Chromium, which is the engine that drives Google Chrome. It affects `Version 57.0.x.x` (`Version 57.0.2987.133` in my case, both Windows 7 and Ubuntu - others report the issue on Macs). It seems that the issue occurs when trying to play a video with "elongated pixels", and goes away when playing a video with "square pixels". Not a video processing expert here, but that's what I've derived from the thread. A work-around would be re-encoding/re-transcoding your videos, if you can.

Based on the Chrome *stable* release schedule, version 58 will be out 4/25/2017 ([source](https://www.chromium.org/developers/calendar)), and based on the [bug thread](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=701060), it should hopefully be fixed by then.

Edit: This should be fixed in Chrome 58 and Chrome 59 ([source](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=701060#c44)).

Comment: Agreed. I'm going to attempt to reprocess the videos in question. The ones that came out of After Effects are fine, the ones generated in FFMPEG and resized have this problem.

Comment: Does this affect Android 5+ webview as well?

Comment: Probably... Since the underlying engine for Chrome probably drives the webview, it might. It also affects (unrelated) Samsung Internet, the native browser for Samsung mobile devices, since it, too, is derived from the Chromium source code.